# Build Magento 2 mobile app without Rest Api

Tags: magento2

i am wondering if it's possible to make mobile app connected directly to Magento 2 db using ReactNative or Flutter, because the app i have now using Rest api its quit slow.

thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

RESTful APIs, in general, improve online and [taxi mobile app development](https://www.softsuave.com/blog/custom-taxi-booking-app-development/) that are delivered over the Internet. Mobile apps are becoming more scalable, and they are also becoming easier to adapt.